# Save data if someone is leaving the webpage or closing the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, browser, dom-events

I am trying to save data if someone is trying to leave the site. This application needs to show user a message stating that he will be moved away from the site and if he clicks on leave then before leaving there will be a data that needs to be saved. I have tried native confirm boxes as well as custom designed options.

In case of custom design, I will like to do something like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    $('#modal-popup').show();       }
```

But this really does not give me the desired result. I am trying to map what I want to do below. Please help.

Closing the tab --> Show a confirmation --> if someone accepts ---> Ajax call ---> else just let the page be as it is.

Answer (score 1):

`onbeforeunload` needs an string as return, unfortunaly the code is executed when user click on stay, not on leave https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload. See this:

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json));
  return "";
};
```

Run the code and try to close this tab, then click on stay.

Comment: I need to show a confirm box. When someone says leave the page, I will like to save data and then leave the page. Is that possible?

Comment: @ShivKumarGanesh If you see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload#Browser_compatibility Custom text support is removed, so is the same using return "" and return "something custom" the text is provided by browser, and always the remain code is executed when user clicks on stay. then, the best approach in my opinion is save data always and when user click on stay, since the text provided by browser prevents user for unsaved changes.

Comment: so the situation is that you delete a certain data if the user leaves the browser. If he dosent leave then we have it as such i.e no request.